# SWFAddress and AJAX

Tags: ajax, swfaddress

I'd like to use SWFAddress in an AJAX project. On the web site there are some examples but any tutorial.
Do you know where I can find a quick guide to implement  SWFAddress on my web site?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found any docs either, but i guess this is the easiest way to implement it:

1- Add this function in your document.ready()

```
 SWFAddress.onChange = function() { //on url change
    try {
        var thePath = SWFAddress.getPathNames(); //get&split url
        if (thePath[0] == 'one') go('one'); //if url is #one do something
        if (thePath[0] == 'two') go('two'); //if url is #two do something
    } catch(e) {}
 }
```

2- Add appropriate anchors on your links (a href="#one").